# Is it signalled that you should run `makeglossaries`?

Tags: pdftex, glossaries

In the comments below [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32786/make-glossary-with-c-c-c-c), it came up that there is no warning in the outputs of LaTeX build tools like `pdflatex` if you use a document that uses a glossary but have yet to run `makeglossaries`.

Is this true? Is there really no such warning? I checked the occurrences of `warning` and `glossar` (so both singular and plural are found) (case-insensitively) in the output of `pdflatex` and didn't find any such warning. Does it – by any chance – use neither of these terms / substrings?

If there is no such warning: Is this the fault of `pdflatex` or the `glossaries` package?

Comment: To expand the question, the warning I requested should suggest to rerun `makeglossaries` whenever it's needed, not only when the `file.gls` is missing (nor always, otherwise would be pretty useless and noisy).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no way of telling if the glossaries need *updating* (just as there's no way of telling if the table of contents, list of figures etc needs updating) but you can tell if `makeglossaries` is required as part of the build process by inspecting the `.aux` file.

The `\makeglossaries` command automatically writes information to the `.aux` file solely for the benefit of build tools. The actual definitions of these commands simply ignore their arguments. This information is used by `makeglossaries` and `makeglossaries-lite`, and the commands are described in the section [Note to Front-End and Script Developers](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:notedev) of the `glossaries` user manual, but they are summarised below.

`\@istfilename{`*filename*`}`

This indicates that `makeindex` or `xindy` is required. The *filename* is the custom style file generated by `glossaries`. If it ends with `.xdy` then `xindy` is required (with `-M`*filename* without the `.xdy` extension), otherwise `makeindex` should be used (with `-s`*filename*).

`\@newglossary{`*label*`}{`*log*`}{`*out-ext*`}{`*in-ext*`}`

This indicates the file extensions needed by the glossary identified by *label*. There will be a separate `\@newglossary` for each defined glossary. Neither `xindy` nor `makeindex` need to know *label*, but the label is needed with the `xindy` option to identify the language and code page settings for each glossary (see below) and is also useful for transcript messages.

`\@glsorder{`*order*`}`

This indicates whether word or letter ordering is required where *order* is either `word` or `letter`. With `makeindex` letter ordering requires the `-l` switch with `xindy` you need to use `-M ord/letorder`.

`\@gls@extramakeindexopts{`*options*`}`

This may not occur, but if it's present *options* must be passed to `makeindex`. The most common occurrence is `\@gls@extramakeindexopts{-g}` which is triggered by a change in the quote character:

```
\GlsSetQuote{+}
```

(This command may only be used with `makeindex`.)

The next two commands only occur when using `xindy`:

`\@xdylanguage{`*label*`}{`*language*`}`

This indicates that the glossary identified by *label* should have the given language. (Passed to `xindy` with `-L`.) This is usually the document language label which may not be the same as the `xindy` language label. (`makeglossaries` has a set of mappings that convert `babel` labels to known `xindy` languages. The light-weight Lua `makeglossaries-lite` doesn't.) If the build tool can't translate the language labels the document must set the correct `xindy` language.

`\@gls@codepage{`*label*`}{`*code*`}`

This is the code page (passed to `xindy` with `-C`). Again, it may need conversion by the build tool from the `inputenc` label to one recognised by `xindy`.

So the simplest check to determine if `makeglossaries` is need is to search for `\@istfilename{`*filename*`}` in the `.aux` file. If you want to by-pass `makeglossaries` and explicitly run `makeindex` or `xindy`, you need to check for all the other commands.

Comment: The `No file jobname.gls` warning doesn't help to rerun the `makeglossaries` program after the file has been created.  That's the point of my request to add an explicit warning.

Comment: @giordano You can find out if `\makeglossaries` is present in the document by searching for `\@istfilename` in the `.aux` file, which will tell you if `makeglossaries` is needed to build the document, but the problem is that there's no way of telling if `makeglossaries` needs re-running any more than `\printindex` can tell if `makeindex` needs re-running. All kinds of things can make the glossary or index out of date: adding/indexing new terms, adding more text that alters the page numbers, removing material. It doesn't work in the same way as `\ref`/`\label`.

Comment: I've rewritten my answer. I was confused by your request for warnings, when it seems to actually be instructions you want.